How to use darken/lighten in scss files with kendo-theme-default v8+
Since updating to use kendo-theme-default 8.2.1, I keep getting compiler errors. I have run the migration script that the provided, but especially running into errors using darken/lighten. I have tried k-color-darken/lighten and that doesn't work either. Here are some errors that I'm getting:
    ./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
$color: var(--kendo-color-error, #f44336) is not a color.
   ╷
92 │     @return darken( $color, $amount );
   │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-core/scss/functions/_color.import.scss 92:13  k-color-darken()

The above error I believe is triggered by this sass code:
.k-chip.error {
  background-color: k-color( error );
  color: k-color-darken(k-color( error ), 35%) !important;
}

I have also tried something different like this:
  &.success {
    color: darken(#{k-color( success )}, 25%) !important;
    background-color: lighten(#{k-color( success )}, 25%) !important;
  }

which results in this error:
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
$color: var(--kendo-color-success, #4caf50) is not a color.
   ╷
42 │     color: darken(#{k-color( success )}, 25%) !important;
   │            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Any reason you don't just leverage toggling between default-main.css and default-main-dark.css?

Yes. This is only for a specific element and not the entire theme. I was able to solve my issue by simply creating variables for those colors instead of using k-color.

That makes sense, I misunderstood the issue.
